# Wordpress Ajax Call returns 0 on POST, data on GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm stumbling on the following strange issue, i've got a simple wp ajax function like this:

```
function send_contact_form_callback(){
  die('test');
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_contact_form', 'send_contact_form_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_contact_form', 'send_contact_form_callback' );
```

And js:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {action: 'send_contact_form'}
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.error("error");
});
```

When I make a POST request the function returns 0, but when I make a GET request it logs 'test'. How is this possible? Both request are returning a 200 status code.

Comment: What does your PHP code contain?

Comment: The first code block

Comment: okay so same piece of code working perfect for me. I think you should give more explanation or more code.

Comment: Yup... There's something else altering the response.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner, there's no more code then this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Havent't thought of that, something could be clearing POST.